# Why doesn't this Label matrix display correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a label grid in Windows Forms, but only one of the columns gets displayed:

```
rows = columns = 20;
letters = new Label[rows, columns];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        letters[i, j] = new Label();
        letters[i, j].Parent = this;
        letters[i, j].Name = i + "_" + j;
        letters[i, j].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        letters[i, j].Location = new Point(20 + 20 * i, 20 + 20 * j);
        letters[i, j].Visible = true;
        letters[i, j].Text = "A";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried using the debugger to see where you are going wrong..?

Comment: Use a `TableLayoutPanel` instead of trying to layout your controls manually. Also if you want to show some text in a grid layout `DataGridView` is suitable for you.

Comment: @MethodMan I have now, and i and j don't have any problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign a `Size` property, so the labels just contain a default size (with big `Width`) that overlaps the others.

```
// ...
letters[i, j].Size = new Size(20, 20);
// ...
```